# xampp Mysql not starting while set as service

Tags: mysql, xampp

I'm using xampp v1.8.1

While not installing Mysql and Apache as services, everything is ok and I can run both of them on default ports.

but when I install them as services only Apache runs normally. but Mysql is frozen at "Attempting to start MySQL service..." and there is no error in its log file and nothing in xampp control panel log.

there is no problem with port numbers because it can run on default port without the service checkbox checked

FYI my OS is: Windows Server 2008 SP2.

thanks

Comment: Did you started xampp-control as admin?

Comment: Yes, but nothing changed by running as admin

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved by using the xampp installer instead of extracted zip archive. It seems that there is some problems with the config in the portable edition.